# Multilines in Equation

Tags: equations, align

my equation is too long so I want to break into multiple lines while keeping it aligned. Most suggestions point towards begin{align*} but I want to keep it as equation. Please help!

```
 \begin{equation} \begin{split}
     \frac{dn_{j}}{dt}\ =\ n_{j,\ in}\ -\ n_{j,\ out}\ +\ A_{m}\ \Big[ \sum_{i}\ J_{i,j}\ +\  J_{w}\ +\\ (k-1)\ (e_{d,H^+}+1) J_{H^+, BP}\ +\
 k\ (e_{d,OH^-}+1) J_{OH^-, BP}\ -\  J_{diss}\ \Big] \end{split}
 \end{equation}\\
```

[image]

Comment: `multline` is more suitable than `align` for a long wrapped equation as there is no alignmemt, But why have you all the `\ `? and never have `\\ ` after a math display.

Comment: What is your problem, exactly?

Answer (score 7):

I propose one of these solutions with some improvements in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{esdiff} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \diff{n_{j}}{t} = n_{j,\text{in}} - n_{j,\text{out}} + A_{m} \smash[b]{\biggl[\sum_{i}} J_{i,j} &+ J_{w} %
                        + (k-1)\ (e_{d,H^+}+1) J_{H^+, BP} \\%
                    & {}+ k (e_{d,OH^-}+1) J_{OH^-, BP}- J_\text{diss} \biggr]
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
    \diff{n_{j}}{t} = n_{j,\text{in}} - n_{j,\text{out}} + A_{m} \smash[b]{\biggl[\sum_{i}} J_{i,j} + J_{w}%\\%
                    + (k-1)(e_{d,H^+}+1) J_{H^+, BP} \\+
                      k (e_{d,OH^-}+1) J_{OH^-, BP}- J_\text{diss} \biggr]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use equation/split but I think multline is more suitable here as there is no alignment. Also never use `\Big` always `\Bigr` and `\Bigl` also use `\mathrm` not math italic for mult-letter words.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


split
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
     \frac{dn_{j}}{dt}&=n_{j,in}-n_{j,\mathrm{out}}+A_{m}\Bigl[ \sum_{i}J_{i,j}+ J_{w}+\\
&(k-1)(e_{d,H^+}+1) J_{H^+, BP}+ k(e_{d,OH^-}+1) J_{OH^-, BP}- J_{\mathrm{diss}}\Bigr] 
\end{split}
 \end{equation}

multline
 \begin{multline}
     \frac{dn_{j}}{dt}=n_{j,in}-n_{j,\mathrm{out}}+A_{m}\Bigl[ \sum_{i}J_{i,j}+ J_{w}+\\
(k-1)(e_{d,H^+}+1) J_{H^+, BP}+ k(e_{d,OH^-}+1) J_{OH^-, BP}- J_{\mathrm{diss}}\Bigr] 
\end{multline}




\end{document}
```